# Why does JAXB handle extensions differently?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

Consider the following XSD file:

```
<xs:element name="person" type="Person"/>
<xs:element name="teacher" type="Teacher"/>

<xs:complexType name="Person">
    <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="age" type="xs:int"/>
       <xs:element name="sex" type="xs:string"/>
       <xs:element name="fullname" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Teacher">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="Person">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="school" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="grade" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="subject" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

I used JAXB to generate Java classes for these complex types. The strange thing is, the Teacher class was annotated with @XmlRootElement, whereas the Person class was not.

Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 1):

Top level elements with anonymous complex types get `@XmlRootElement` annotations generated on them.  Top level elements with a named complex type have `@XmlElementDecl` annotations on the generated `ObjectFactory`.  `Teacher` should not have been generated with an `@XmlRootElement` unless some sort of binding customization is used.

**For More Information**

I have writtent more about this on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html

Comment: Ah, good point. I have revised my code to include the two element declarations I omitted. I think this explains why Teacher is annotated with XmlRootElement. But it still doesn't explain why Person is not annotated with XmlRootElement.